# Implict rule cancellation in Makefile

Tags: makefile, u-boot

I have come across the following line in U-boot Makefile ( https://github.com/siemens/u-boot/blob/master/Makefile#L128 ) with comment "Cancel implicit rules on top Makefile". 
Can you help me to understand the following line, how/what will happen while executing the following line by make utility.

```
$(CURDIR)/Makefile Makefile: ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles):

> If you know that one or more of your makefiles cannot be remade and you want to keep make from performing an implicit rule search on them, perhaps for efficiency reasons, you can use any normal method of preventing implicit rule look-up to do so. For example, you can write an explicit rule with the makefile as the target, and an empty recipe.

And that is exactly what `$(CURDIR)/Makefile Makefile: ;` rule does - it has an [empty recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Recipes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understood now that it is an empty recipe. Now my doubht is about the target name which is `"$(CURDIR)/Makefile Makefile"`. We can mention `"$(CURDIR)/Makefile"`, is there any reason using the `Makefile` twice in the target name.

Comment: @user3693586 I am not sure how these 2 targets could refer to different files. I would expect them to refer to the same file.

Comment: Both refers to the same Makefile only. My doubht is whether we can use `"$(CURDIR)/Makefile : ;"` instead of `"$(CURDIR)/Makefile Makefile: ;"` .

Comment: There is only one Makefile where I am executing make command and CURDIR also pointing to the same path where make command is executing.

Comment: @user3693586 Looks like `$(CURDIR)/Makefile` is unnecessary here. If you run `make -p` you should see that it only checks the timestamp of `Makefile` target, `$(CURDIR)/Makefile` target is not examined.

Comment: As per the comment @ https://github.com/siemens/u-boot/blob/master/Makefile#L127, the requirement is to cancel implicit rules for top Makefile. If we write empty recipe as `"Makefile: ;"` then implicit rules will be cancelled for the top Makefile?

Comment: @user3693586 I do not think I can provide any new information for you here.